# Angular updates validity of existing FormArray elements when new element is added

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

And I don't want this. Because I'm validating each element of `FormArray` asynchronously, I want validators only to run when necessary (i.e. when value of the control they're added to really changes). I also find this behaviour strange because validators don't get executed when value of `FormArray` changes, only when new element is added.

replication: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-tkdu1n?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `FormArray` executes the validator for every nested `FormControl` when a new `FormControl` is pushed inside it, and there's nothing to do about it...

So I forked your stackblitz and I created a stateful validator with a closure, and it did the trick:

```
form: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormArray([]);
  this.form.push(new FormControl("test", null, this.validatorFactory()));
}

addControl() {
  this.form.push(new FormControl(null, null, this.validatorFactory()));
}

validatorFactory() {
  let previousValue;
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    if (c.value == previousValue) {
      return Observable.of(null);
    } else {
      previousValue = c.value;
      return Observable.of(null).delay(1000);
    }
  };
}
```

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-qxdyfl?file=app/app.component.ts)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just change the

```
return Observable.of(null).delay(1000);
```

to

```
return Observable.of(null).delay(0);
```

When you make delay 1000ms you also disable and block the reachability of the statuses of the other instances ( or values), however, when you make delay 0, it does not deal with other instances just checks the current one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I cannot set the delay when using real services instead of mocked ones...

Comment: It's still calling validators for each of the controls obviously, just the delay is gone.

Comment: Of course, you cant get away from this because you use single validator for them, but in view it does not act like that when you eliminate the delay. If you want to avoid from it you should use new instance of FormArray for each value which of course is terrible idea. Best way I think is doing the validation yourself instead of using FormArray.